# The usage of where as a relative pronoun

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns

> Furthermore, the act of voting necessarily ignores how strongly each individual feels about the matter being voted on or the consequences that a final decision may impose. And even under the best of circumstances, voting necessarily means that some group of people will not get what they want and if severely beaten by the majority, may leave the group or retaliate. *Voting can therefore only produce satisfying decisions **where** is unanimity of opinion.*

In this sentence, "where" is used for what in grammar?

(Sorry I don't have a link and I have no idea where this passage is from because I got a paper form the eng teacher in school.)

Comment: It's bad grammar. It should be, "*...where **there** is unanimity of opinion*".

Comment: Here is the correct final sentence: Voting can therefore only produce satisfying decisions where everyone is extremely tolerant or there is unanimity of opinion.